# How to customize tree view loading time?

Tags: treeview, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I am working with the TreeView in OpenERP. But my tree view takes a long time to load. How can customize that?

[image]

I have defined  a `Many2many` field in the `product.product` model.

```py
product_ids = fields.Many2many(
    comodel_name='product.product', 
    relation='product_procurement_rel',
    column1='process_id',
    column2='product_id',
    string='Products'
)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Sometimes the `name_get` method (at least in previous versions) takes too long time in retrieving all the many2many field names. Is it that what's happening to you?